# how to save image using python?

Tags: python, image, jsp, image-manipulation, mechanize

I want to save a .jsp image from a web page in to my computer using python.

I have tried many methods including

retrieve function in mechanize and
urllib.urlretrieve('http://example.com/img.jsp', 'img.jsp')

but the problem is when I try to open the image using the image library it throws the following error

```
    File "code.py", line 71, in extract_image
    im = Image.open(image_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
```

I have even tried saving the image in .png format, but its not working.
But I can do the save manually by going to the image url and then saving the image.

Pls help!

Comment: And just what *does* the file contain?

Comment: it can be any random image even a background image.

Comment: Are you going to make me repeat my question?

Comment: Don't you mean jpg? JSP it's not an image format.

Comment: use python imaging library for the same.

Comment: Do you actually wan't to save an image ON a Java Server Page? And your question doesn't imply, that you wan't to open the image.

Comment: you can use .jsp as images..like <img src="img.jsp">.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information, but my guess is that the web server isn't responding the way you think it is -- did you peek the HTTP traffic with Fiddler or Firebug or look at what's in the file?

Can you get a copy of the image some other way -- if so, compare that to what you downloaded programmatically.

Finally, I am not sure what a JSP image is -- if img.jsp is a JavaServerPage that responds with an image, that doesn't make the image a JSP image -- it's still in the format that corresponds to its Content-type.